# Mac PackageMaker "Destination Select" step A) skipping B)Option permanently disabled

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I have a software that is bundled using PackageMaker. When i run the installer, the first screen "Introduction" shows up. Clicking on "Continue" takes the user to the 3rd screen "Installation Type" rather than taking the user to 2nd screen "Destination Select". This issue isn't reproducible at will.

Also, I have another issue with this "Destination Select" step.
I have enabled only "Install for me only" option in the Destination Select screen. Default behavior in this screen is for the user to click on this option and then the Continue button is enabled to proceed to 3rd screen.  At times, this option "Install for me only" is permanently disabled. Even clicking on it doesn't enable the option. Is there something in the PackageMaker that I need to do/change/use to make this work all the time?

I have experimented a lot on both these issues but have been reaching a deadend always. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I'm running into this too.. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `Known Issues and Workarounds` in [Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re/11487658#11487658)

The Destination Select Pane which you get from `<domains enable_anywhere ... />` is generally buggy.